# How to get an access to Magento App code which is in Docker container

Tags: magento, docker, docker-compose

I haven't managed to find the solution how to get an access to Magento App code, which is in Docker container, at my host machine to have a chance to develop in my favorite IDE.

In detail, I use this image (https://github.com/alexcheng1982/docker-magento) to get Magento 1.9.

I built containers by the command "**docker-compose up -d**" and everything is fine. I can see my site that works fine at http://local.magento .

But, as a developer I want to open the app in PHPStorm editor on my host machine. How to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a volume

    `volumes:
     - ./src/:/var/www/html`

Data will be added in local src folder.